# Flask API: Internal Server Error while dumping 'Final_df' data

Tags: python, flask

```py
Final_df #My DataFrame

app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def finaldata():
    data=Final_df
    json_dump=json.dumps(data)
    
    return json_dump
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(port=1000)
```

I am trying to create an API and dump my 'Final_df' data but I am getting:

`"Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."`

How can I remove my error?

Comment: 1) Look at the server logs, not the HTTP response 2) `jason.dumps()` isn't a valid Python function 3) You don't need pandas dataframes to return JSON in Flask

Comment: @OneCricketeer  --I have Updated the function error.-- My current error is TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable
127.0.0.1 - - [25/May/2023 02:24:11] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -  and also ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]

Comment: I just want to create an api to show my own data where I have done some data cleaning

Comment: Pandas already has the function `df.to_json()`, or even `df.to_html()` if you're just trying to display it.

Comment: When you search the error `Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable`, what types of solutions do you get? What made you use `json.dumps()`?